# Dynamic date and time with moment.js and setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, momentjs

I'm trying to find out how I can display dynamic date and time using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Apparently I can't figure out to use setInterval properly.

If possible I'd prefer not to use jQuery as moment.js dosn't need it.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/37fLF/2/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datetime = $('#datetime'),
        date = moment(new Date()),
        update = function(){
            datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
        };
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});​
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've made a few modifications in your code:

Note that the method update is now outside the `ready` event handler

code:

```
var datetime = null,
        date = null;

var update = function () {
    date = moment(new Date())
    datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    datetime = $('#datetime')
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

working demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/37fLF/4/)

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. Thank you!

Comment: updated with newer version of moment.js because the jsfiddle is broken: http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/37fLF/217/

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful example. Could you help me how to use UTC time rather than local time for the same code.

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
date = moment(new Date());
```

inside the update function. Now you're just printing the same date every second ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked ;)
PS: The first line of my post should go
"Hello everyone - this is my first post here".
I tried to edit it afterwards but it would not update.

Comment: I think you need some points before you can edit stuff. I think I've been able to push it, but it might just be for me ..

Comment: How do I make line breaks in the comments?  

Do you know how I can "escape" the string?  

Like if I have:  
Monday, May 14th 2012, 10:51:01 pm  
  
And want to output for example:  
Monday, May 14th 2012, the time is 10:51:01 pm  
  
If I write this:  
('dddd Do MMMM YYYY, '+'the time is'+' h:mm:ss')  
  
"the time is" becomes: t10e ti55e i01.

Comment: Do this: `datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY') + ' The time is: ' + date.format('h:mm:ss a'))`;

Comment: You can also just do `date = moment()`, as calling moment with no parameters is the same as `moment(new Date())`. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/

Answer (score 3):

Again, thanks for your answers. The code I ended up with follows.
(Note danish i18n)

```
moment.lang('da');

var datetime = null, date = null;

var datetime_update = function() {
  date = moment(new Date());
  datetime.html(date.format('[Lige nu: ] dddd [d.] Do MMMM YYYY [kl.] HH:mm:ss'));
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  datetime = $('#datetime');
  datetime_update();
  setInterval(datetime_update, 1000);
});
```

**EDIT**: Here nine months after I asked this quesiton I figured out this way to do it without jQuery (as I initially asked). Here it is:

```
function date_time() {
  now = moment().format('dddd [d.] Do MMMM YYYY [kl.] HH:mm:ss');
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = now;
  setTimeout(function () { date_time(); }, 1000);
}
date_time();
```

And then of course use it with an HTML ID like:

```
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it goes by me and its working u can check it here

```
HTML
```

< asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='' >

```
JavaScript
< script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function date_time() 
{
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerHTML = dt;
setTimeout(function () { date_time(); }, 1000);
}
date_time();
< /script>
```