# Moment.js dynamically update time in seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to *display a clock* that *updates every second* (e.g. *1/5/2015 12:05:**01*** then *1/5/2015 12:05:**02***, etc.) using **moment.js**.

I found *previous solutions* to my question (see [Dynamic date and time with moment js and setinterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590461/dynamic-date-and-time-with-moment-js-and-setinterval)), however it *doesn't work with the newest version of moment.js (v2.11.0)*. The solution provided uses v2.6.

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

it seems to work fine for me. For the same code. And only the moment.min.js pointed to **v2.11.0**

Have a look at the code(credits: to MilkyWayJoe)-

```
var datetime = null,
        date = null;

var update = function () {
    date = moment(new Date())
    datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    datetime = $('#datetime')
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

Working fiddle with **v2.11.0** - [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bozzmob/029bxLma/)

Comment: I was loading the javascript file incorrectly. Thanks for the quick answer. Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: Ahhh! I do silly mistakes all the time. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 4):

A working compact solution.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtdoe6mf/)

HTML

```
<div id="datetime"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var update = function() {
    document.getElementById("datetime")
    .innerHTML = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
}
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution you mentioned does work for moment.js v2.11.0.

Code:

```
var datetime = null,
        date = null;

var update = function () {
    date = moment(new Date())
    datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    datetime = $('#datetime')
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37fLF/443/)

However the JSFiddle in that accepted answer with the previous solution does not work giving the following error.

```
"Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/timrwood/moment/1.6.2/moment.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."
```

It can be fixed by simply loading the script from a proper CDN like so:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.0/moment.min.js
```