# moment js format date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm getting the following format of date from db
`2016 1 24 12:00am`

I want make it as moment object so I can do some processing with it

I tried something like below

`m = moment('2016 1 24 12:00am').format('YYYY M D ha');`

it says `invalid date`

how to parse this type of strings?

I will get year, month, date and time from different vars, I can construct string like `2016-1-24-12:00am` still it throws error

[image]

Comment: See the docs for recognized date formats: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass format as a second argument to convert a string to a moment object

```
m = moment('2016 1 24 12:00am', 'YYYY M D ha');
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the date your DB returns is not parsable. Moment.js allows you to create a moment object with custom date but you have to specify a format of that day as a second argument e.g.

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format

Comment: zohaib Ijaz solution works fine, Is there any issue parsing like that?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625764/moment-js-dynamically-update-time-in-seconds/34625878#34625878) on Stackoverflow.

```
date = moment(new Date())
datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
```

And [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bozzmob/029bxLma/) from the above question. It has a great answer and working.